# Unable to hide columns in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

What I am trying to do is hide an entire column if the content is all null.

```
<mx:DataGrid width="100%" dataProvider="{service}" id="dg1">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Location Origin" dataField="originLocation" visible="{data.originLocationExists}" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Location Destination" dataField="destinationLocation" visible="{data.destinationLocationExists}" />  
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Location Group Origin" dataField="originLocationGroup" visible="{data.originLocationGroupExists}" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Location Group Destination" dataField="destinationLocationGroup" visible="{data.destinationLocationGroupExists}"/>               
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

In the sample above, sometimes all the data in the "Location Origin" will be null, so under the visible property I put a value which is either true or false depending on the data. But even when all the data is null and the visible property equals false, it still stays visible.

What can I do to fix this? And I am running in Flex 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go along with J_A_X's answer, you could also [add an eventListener for the dataProvider's `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE` event](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/12/16/detecting-when-the-data-provider-of-a-datagrid-control-changes-in-flex/) and then evaluate if you need to [hide any columns](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=154229) or not.

Comment: The 'one more link' is unavailable now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you grasped the concept of columns properly.  Columns are not item renderers.  They do not receive a 'data' property from the dataProvider given unless you have a something on your code somewhere setting the 'data' property of your container (all components have a 'data' property for possible use in item renderers).

So, essentially, `data.originLocationExists` will always be null and will never bind, making your columns always visible.  Maybe you just wanted to do `{service.originLocationExists}` instead, since that would be consistent with your data as long as 'service' has that actually property in it.